# Relate name with found function

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, match

I have a list of institutions with ID's and I have the same list but not in the same order as this image:

[image]

So I don't have it in the same order the next step is that this institutions have different areas and some institutes have some others don't. Like this list:

[image]

I have this formula `=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(C$1,$J2:$O2,0)),"Found","Not Found")` that helps me to look for the area in that row but is not in the same order this gives me errors, so I would like to look for the institute name in the range and look for the areas available in that institution row:
Here is the image of the error:

You can see in the image that the founds and not founds are not correct

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It can be achieved using a helper table where you first sort your `J2:Q14` range using

```
=SORT(J2:Q14,1,1)
```

You then use the following in cell `C2`

```
=IFERROR(IF(HLOOKUP(C$1,$J17:$Q$29,1,0)=C$1,"Fount",),"NOT")
```

Drag the cell down and right to fill all other cells.

*(Of course the sorted table can be in another sheet altogether)*

[image]

Comment: I like the solutions but in some cases are names and the names are not sorted by A-Z you now is more like historical added institutions with names like General motors then Ford so I need other solution but thanks

Comment: Can you share a [test sheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383)?

Comment: It is the same as your image. No "General motors" or "Ford". Doesn't help much :(

Comment: I made the changes sorry

Comment: [I don't see an issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A6C0e.png) there. It all works as expected.